# Why does the Google App Engine documentation emphasize JDO over JPA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jdo

Most of the docs for Google App Engine are written for JDO. Only one page of docs are devoted to using JPA. Is this because JDO is more suited to App Engine or was there some other reason for the preferential treatment given to JDO?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JPA is oriented towards mapping java objects onto relational databases.  App Engine is not a relational database.  JDO is more agnostic about the backend you persist objects to, so it is a better fit.

Update: I should mention that the JPA/JDO debate can get heated sometimes, like in this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418219/jdo-vs-jpa-for-java-on-google-app-engine/1418281) for example.

Comment: Agree with what Peter says, and would add that in the DataNucleus docs we provide equal converage of JDO and JPA, allowing users to choose what fits best for them. GAE/J's docs are obviously more slanted to their particular datastore. Debates about persistence API always gets heated yes, due to some groups having vested interests ...